# Asking a small group of two or more people a personal question?

Tags: politeness

So, I visit casual group chats regularly, both in person and over internet messaging, and often a question is asked, "How is everyone doing?" Or, something along those lines.

Now, this all seems fine and dandy. In a perfect case, each person would respond, and then the questioner could comment after each other user has responded and relate their answers to how he or she is doing. But, it almost never works out like that. Here's the problem.

Most people like to respond with their own answer, then immediately ask how the person asking the question is doing, such as:

Questioner: *How is everybody?*

Responder 1: *I'm fine, thank you. And how are you?*

Responder 2: *???*

How would one continue that? Does Responder 2 simply state how they are, and ask the same question to the questioner? Or, should the questioner answer Responder 1, then let Responder 2 answer how they are afterward? I don't see a polite way to continue this, because once someone asks the questioner how they are doing back, any other answers to the question are effectively halted due to politeness toward both the Questioner and Responder 1. Should personal questions directed at a group simply not be used, and each person should be talked to individually? Or is there a polite way for one person to ask a group of people something that they're expecting a response for?

Comment: I don't see why other answers should be halted. You asked a question to the group, everyone can answer. There's no need for others to repeat the return question, but they can still answer for themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a language question, it seems more like a question about how to participate in different social groups.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question about the English language.

Comment: @CanisLupus Is there a better forum to ask this type of question? I still don't have a solid answer and am strongly seeking one. Goodwin's answer is close, but it still doesn't define how to order this in a casual situation. In an organized therapy session, yes, a round-robin sort of personal answer would be fine.

Comment: I don't. You might want to search for a conversational forum. Or a cultural forum, depending on what your question is motivated by. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I quite see what Barmar means, both times, and to ask the question was to miss the point of English conversational conventions.

Going back several stages, when we are formally introduced One holds out his hand and says ‘How d’you do?’ but that is not a question and it certainly doesn’t require an answer.

Two's response - not answer - should be either exactly the same ‘How d’you do?’ or something very like ‘Pleased to meet you.’

That’s it. The formalities have been observed and although it would be unusual, it would also be quite acceptable for any of the three to say something like ‘The pleasure is mine. Would you excuse me? I’m just going over there…’ then simply turn on his heel and leave…

It makes no difference whether that person says ‘Would you excuse me?’ or ‘Please excuse me’ or just ‘Excuse me.’ None of them requires any response at all and even if the person really does just ‘go over there’ and stand in another part of the same room that’s odd, not rude. It might be anti-social, but that’s nothing to do with language.

‘Group chats’ might cover a multitude of sins but what you described sounded more like a group therapy session in which, yes, each person would respond - or have a chance to.

‘… then the questioner could comment after each other user has responded and relate their answers to how he or she is doing’ certainly doesn’t sound to me like four or five people sitting round a table over beer or wine or tea… That sounds like 10 or 12 or more sitting in a big circle, formal circle with nothing in the middle, run by a facilitator, rather than entertained by a host. That would apply as well to a conversational language class as to a therapy session and in either case the idea would be intensified by using ‘user’ instead of ‘person.’

In the unlikely event that in a real social setting, one person asked everyone else at once ‘How are you?’ let alone ‘How is everyone doing?’ the expected response would be for all to say ‘Fine, thank you…’ very probably with no ‘… and how are you?’ and then pause; the pause ending when either someone thought of something natural to say, or the host dutifully asked a conventional ‘ice-breaking’ question, perhaps even as banal as ‘What do you think of the weather?’ or 'Did you all have a safe journey?'

Either way, how is your Three going to come across asking One exactly the same ‘How are you?’ that was answered when Two asked it a minute earlier?

Beneath all of that, ‘How are you?’ in any ordinary tone of voice isn’t a personal question.

A ‘personal’ question isn’t something asked of an individual rather than a group. A ‘personal’ question is one that many if not people would mind answering in front of any gathering but a therapy group, or would mind being asked even in private by anyone but very close friends or relatives.

Beyond those fairly strict ideas, so formulaic they might even be found in some text books, we certainly would be going beyond language and considering how to participate in different social groups.